# OpenX Google Ads causing javascript errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, adsense, openx

In our website, we have Google Ads served via OpenX on some pages. In those pages, this error appears in the Google Chrome browser console. It appears lot of times when the page is being loaded.

The error is in the form of

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://ox-d.<openxdomain>.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://real website domain". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

This error does not come in any page where there are no GoogleAds. (Other pages have OpenX banners that does not serve google ads. Those does not cause this issue.) All the OpenX banners are iframes.

Is this occurring because of an issue in our site? or is this an issue of OpenX/GoogleAds/Google Chrome?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This occures because Google Chrome has more stronger security crossdomain politics than other browsers.

First of all, check `iframe` tag. It should ends with `</iframe>`, not just `/>`
Than, you should try to remove protocol scheme (`http[s]:`) from iframe src attribute.

For example:

At the end of all, you should "grant access" to your

> `http://real website domain`

on your openx server by setting

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: real.website.domain
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
```

Answer (score -1):

If your OpenX was installed in some other domain then some times google not allowed to placed their ad code in iframe .

Please try javascript invocation code type for GoogleAds and this this should be working fine. Check and put your comment here .